# How to take ownership over an existing Ubuntu Software Center app?

Tags: software-center, application-development, permissions, download-manager, uget

My name is Michael Tunnell and I am one of the project members of the download manager, uGet. uGet has been out of date in Ubuntu for over a YEAR and we are trying to fix that. (You can verify my involvement by going to http://uget.visuex.com/about)

The new Developer Portal and the My Apps feature of the Ubuntu site looks very useful for those who are creating new apps but uGet has been around for years and there doesn't seem to be a place where I can take ownership of the app in the USC.

The USC has version 1.8.2 and we are currently on 1.10.3 (it has been outdated for over a year)

We don't want to submit a new app because uGet is already in the USC and people have already installed it from there...we just want to update the existing version to the current version and be able to do that as needed.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Actually, the `uget` package is maintained in Debian. The unstable release of Debian ships with [uGet 1.10.3](http://packages.debian.org/unstable/uget), and the same is also true for  the [development version of Ubuntu](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/uget).

In order to have the package updated in the current stable releases of Ubuntu (lucid, precise, quantal and raring), you can [ask for a backport](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuBackports#Requesting_a_Backport) using the procedure detailed in the Ubuntu wiki.

Comment: That is interesting that it is done via Debian. Thank you for that info. We have DEBs for precise, quantal and raring so we want to get those backported for sure.

It is curious as to why dev versions of Ubuntu 13.10 run 1.10.3 when all of the stables have been outdated for so long. Maybe Debian took that long to update. Not sure...we are still trying to consolidate our efforts with uGet.

Comment: @Michael, yes, packages in Debian can take some time to be updated. You can communicate with the Debian maintainer of uget to ensure that latest versions are always uploaded in Debian sid/unstable in order to reach the wider communities of both Debian, Ubuntu and their derivatives.

Comment: You can find some helpful information about uget package in here:
http://packages.debian.org/sid/uget
http://packages.qa.debian.org/u/uget.html
You can also reach the maintainer from there.